# Riemannian manifolds $(M/\Gamma_1,g_1)$ and $(M/\Gamma_2,g_2)$ are isometric if and only if $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ are conjugate

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, isometry

This is problem 3.21 of Lee's RM. Let $(M,g)$ be a simply connected Riemannian manifold, and suppose 
$\Gamma_1$ and  $\Gamma_2$ are countable subgroups of $\mathrm{Iso}(M,g)$ acting smoothly, freely, and
properly on $M$.

> Prove that Riemannian manifolds $(M/\Gamma_1,g_1)$ and $(M/\Gamma_2,g_2)$ are isometric if and only if  $\Gamma_1$ and  $\Gamma_2$ are conjugate subgroups of $\mathrm{Iso}(M,g)$

---

*My attempt:* if $\Gamma_1$ and  $\Gamma_2$ are conjugate then there is an isometry $\varphi$ such that
$\varphi\Gamma_1\varphi^{-1}=\Gamma_2$ or $\varphi\Gamma_1=\Gamma_2 \varphi$. One can see that orbit space $\Gamma_1.p$ (=points on $M/\Gamma_1$) map to orbit space $\Gamma_2.\varphi(p)$ (=points on $M/\Gamma_2$) by $\varphi$. call this map $\phi$. Thus $\pi_2\circ \varphi=\phi\circ \pi_1$ where $\pi_i\colon M\to M/\Gamma_i$ are Riemannian covering map. because $\pi_i$s are local isometry so $\phi$ is also a local isometry (Right?). How to proceed?

For converse, if $(M/\Gamma_1,g_1)$ and $(M/\Gamma_2,g_2)$ are isometric by $\psi$, because $M$ is simply connected therefore there is a unique lift  $\widetilde{\psi}:M/\Gamma_1\to M$ such that $\pi_2\circ \widetilde{\psi}=\psi$. Now how to involve $\Gamma_i$s?
$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
    M @>>> M\\
    @V \displaystyle \pi_1 V V  @VV \displaystyle{\pi_2} V\\
    M/\Gamma_1 @>>\displaystyle \psi> M/\Gamma_2
    \end{CD}$$

Honestly I don't know how to reach to the goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\Gamma_1 = g \Gamma_2 g^{-1}$. Then $g:M \to M$ induces an isometry $\bar{g}:M/\Gamma_1 \to M/\Gamma_2$ since for every $\gamma_1 \in \Gamma_1,$ there is a (unique) $\gamma_2 \in \Gamma_2$ such that $g\gamma_1 m= \gamma_2 g m$.

On the other hand, suppose $\phi: M/\Gamma_1 \to M/\Gamma_2$ is an isometry. Since $M$ is simply connected and the actions are free and proper, $\Gamma_i$ identifies with the group of deck transformations of $\pi_i:M \to M/\Gamma_i$.

To work with fundamental groups we should really pick a basepoint. Choose $x_0 \in M/\Gamma_1$ and a lift $\tilde{x_0} \in M$. Also choose a lift $\tilde{y_0} \in M$ of $y_0=\phi(x_0) \in M/\Gamma_2$. Then there is a unique lift $\tilde{\phi}:M \to M$ such that $\tilde{\phi}(\tilde{x_0})=\tilde{y_0}$ fitting into your commutative diagram. Now let $\gamma_1 \in \Gamma_1$. Then $\tilde{\phi} \circ \gamma_1 \circ \tilde{\phi}^{-1}$ maps $\tilde{y_0}$ to another lift of $y_0$, and is therefore an element of $\Gamma_2$.

Comment: Your first argument says that if $f:M/{\Gamma_1}\to M/{\Gamma_2}$ bijective then it is an isometry. Right? I can't accept this, all things that it can say is that it is a local isometry.

Comment: $\bar{g}$ is a bijective local isometry of Riemannian manifolds. In particular the pullback of the metric $g_2$ is $g_1$, so it is an isometry.

Comment: Do you know why the proof of [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=JV9m8o-ok6YC&lpg=PA697&ots=6FzgxZ6BoK&dq=induces%20an%20isometry%20by%20quotient&pg=PA697#v=onepage&q=induces%20an%20isometry%20by%20quotient&f=falseI) (p. 697) is a full page and your is 7 lines? Isn't something wrong?

Comment: The question you posted is a little easier than the statement in the book, since you assume the quotient spaces are manifolds. The proof in the book is designed to handle the case when the quotient is just an orbifold.